# Newbie** (Snapping) Cant find "project individual elements" option

Tags: workflow

I am following a tutorial and in the tutorial the option for project individual elements is used but in my Mac OS Blender version 3.0.0 i am given no such option.
any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

My Options:[image]

The Tutorials options i need:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Please follow this GIF**

[image]

Enable the snap option, open the drop-down menu and holding shift ,left click all the 'snap to' options to enable all of them.

Comment: To clarify, that option checkbox will only appear if you have already selected the 'Face' option in the list. Try selected each in turn and you'll see that the available options change depending on the item selected in the list.